# Can not save utf8 with Cleardb heroku

Tags: mysql, playframework, cleardb

When I deploy in heroku, I use ClearDB, I can't insert japanese character, When I remote ClearDB with MySQL workbench, I can handle insert japanese. Problem can is code. I use playframework 2.5

Config in Procfile:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/recruitment -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -    DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
console: target/universal/stage/bin/recruitment -main scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner -usejavacp
```

Connection string in application.conf

```
default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
default.url="jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_abcd"
default.username=username
default.password="password"
```

Any suggest, please tell me, thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve is append "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8" to default.url

```
default.url="jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_abcd?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```